# for Calendars.CONTENT_URI how to detect if calendar is read-only?

Tags: android, calendar

Events for the holidays and birthdays calendars apparently cannot be modified.  In general, how do I tell if a calendar's events are read-only?  I'm guessing I can look at the CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL column.  Anyone know for sure, and what value(s) to check for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to check the value of `CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL`.

You should get all the calendar with the following access level:

> [`CAL_ACCESS_OWNER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#CAL_ACCESS_OWNER)
>   Full access to the calendar
>
> [`CAL_ACCESS_EDITOR`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#CAL_ACCESS_EDITOR)
>   Full access to modify the calendar, but not the
>   access control settings
>
> [`CAL_ACCESS_CONTRIBUTOR`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#CAL_ACCESS_CONTRIBUTOR)
>   Full access to modify the calendar, but not the
>   access control settings
>
> [`CAL_ACCESS_ROOT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#CAL_ACCESS_ROOT)
>   Domain admin

This is an example that returns all the writable calendars:

```
String selection = "(" + CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL + " =  ? OR "
        + CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL + " =  ? OR "
        + CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL + " =  ? OR "
        + CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL + " =  ?)";

String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
        Integer.toString(CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER),
        Integer.toString(CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_EDITOR),
        Integer.toString(CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_CONTRIBUTOR),
        Integer.toString(CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_ROOT)};

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you learn this? I searched quite extensively for documentation but found nothing.

Comment: Also, can you explain in more detail what each of the access levels mean?  Two have the same description.  Apparently there are other access levels, too, which you are not showing.  It would be helpful to know what all of them mean.  All I'm aware of is the terse strings which you have reproduced in your yellow box area.  No descriptions of what them mean.

Comment: The documentation about all the calendar access level can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html). As you can see there are 5 more levels that cannot modify the calendar (`CAL_ACCESS_FREEBUSY`, `CAL_ACCESS_NONE`, `CAL_ACCESS_OVERRIDE`, `CAL_ACCESS_READ`, `CAL_ACCESS_RESPOND`). Every access level in the yellow area is also clickable and open the documentation from where the description was quoted. Unfortunately there are no more detail about the meaning of the single level.

Comment: If you call that documentation.  That's where I started.  It's pretty lame.

Comment: Downvote me if you like.  I still maintain that the existing documentation is crappy.  It's only possible to guess or trace through android source code to really know what some of these mean (yes, some are obvious).  The amount of time I spend trying to get meaning from android documentation significantly slows down my development.  Many other people say the same thing.  Google, start doing it right.

Comment: You are a genius.The mistake I made was looking for answers from the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I'll consider the following to be the correct answer unless someone corrects me.

Via

```
Cursor calCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
      Calendars.CONTENT_URI, 
      projection, // whatever cols you want
      (Calendars.VISIBLE + " = 1 and " +
       Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL + " >= " + Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_CONTRIBUTOR),
      null, 
      Calendars._ID + " ASC");
```

I'm getting a list that does not include the holidays or birthdays calendars.  So, I'm assuming that any calender in the list I get is writeable and, thus, my app can easily make holidays and birthdays read only.  So far that assumption has been working for me.